# How do I configure NodaTime Serialization in .Net 5.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, nodatime

Trying to set up a brand new .Net 5.0 API and the service runs, but I want to use NodaTime and I cannot figure out how to get the serialization settings to work. The below seems to be correct, but getting,

`The JSON value could not be converted to NodaTime.LocalDate`

when trying to send in

```cs
{
    "date": "2021-Jan-01"
}
```

Here is my current config:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet;

namespace src
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
                .AddControllers()
                
                .AddJsonOptions(_ =>
                {
                    new JsonSerializer()
                       .ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd use ISO-8601 dates instead (so "2021-01-01" instead of "2021-Jan-01"). That's the standardized way of representing a date, and it doesn't use culture-sensitive month names.

If you *really* need to use this format, you'd need to remove the `LocalDate` converter populated by NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet and add a new one.

You can copy the "replace converters with a new one" code from [here](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime.serialization/blob/1c4b27e2ae9d118727f03011fa5e010ba95bb4c9/src/NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet/Extensions.cs#L152) - it's slightly unfortunate that you need to copy the code, but it's not something I really want to expose publicly.

Creating a new converter for `LocalDate` is easy, fortunately:

```cs
var pattern = LocalDatePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("uuuu'-'MMM'-'dd");
var converter = new NodaPatternConverter<LocalDate>(pattern);
```

(That doesn't perform the validation that the `LocalDate` is in the ISO calendar like the built-in converters do, but you're unlikely to need that.)