How do I configure NodaTime Instant to LocalDateTime Serialization in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API
I can't figure out how to convert NodaTime's Instant datatype to LocalDateTime or even better to System.DateTime.
I can save Instant to a Postgresql database and then receive it via web service. Web service returns value:
{
    "date" : "2024-05-20T14:21:39Z"
}

If I use solution from this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188327/how-do-i-configure-nodatime-serialization-in-net-5-0
and add to my code this:
options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Remove(NodaConverters.InstantConverter);
options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new NodaPatternConverter<Instant>(InstantPattern.CreateWithCurrentCulture("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(NodaConverters.CreateDateTimeZoneConverter(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));

I can get result
{
    "date" : "2024-05-20 14:21:39"
}

This is almost that what I want, but not at all. My time zone is +2 hours so my local time should be:
{
    "date" : "2024-05-20 16:21:39"
}

Do I have to write my own JsonConverter, or is there any other simpler way to achieve that?

"I can't figure out how to convert NodaTime's Instant datatype to LocalDateTime or even better to System.DateTime." I'm finding it hard to follow how this is relevant to the rest of the question. Is the web service your code, or are you just the client? You seem to be receiving data from the web service for some of the question, and then doing your own serialization at other times. It's hard to help without more clarity.

To answer the precise question Instant.ToDateTimeUtc converts an Instant into DateTime, with a Kind of UTC. But I suspect that's not what you want.

NodaTime provides the zone converter. My time format is different from what you need so I define a custom converter.
Program.cs
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Remove(NodaConverters.InstantConverter);
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new NodaPatternConverter<Instant>(InstantPattern.General));
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new CustomDateTimeConverter());
    });

Controller.cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly DateTimeZone _timeZone;

    public WeatherForecastController()
    {
        //Replace with your zone
        _timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Vilnius"];
    }

    [HttpGet("convert")]
    public IActionResult ConvertInstantToLocal()
    {
        Instant instant = Instant.FromUtc(2024, 5, 20, 14, 21, 39);

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.InZone(_timeZone);

        DateTime dateTime = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified();

        var response = new
        {
            OriginalInstant = instant,
            DateTime = dateTime
        };

        return Ok(response);
    }
}

Custom Converter
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class CustomDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}


